# R text mining package: Allowing to incorporate new documents into an existing corpus

Tags: r, text, text-mining

I was wondering if there is any chance of R's text mining package having the following feature:

```
myCorpus <- Corpus(DirSource(<directory-contatining-textfiles>),control=...)
# add docs
myCorpus.addDocs(DirSource(<new-dir>),control=...)
```

Ideally I would like to incorporate additional documents into the existing corpus.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 11):

You should be able just to use `c(,)` as in

```
> library(tm)
> data("acq")
> data("crude")
> together <- c(acq,crude)
> acq
A corpus with 50 text documents
> crude
A corpus with 20 text documents
> together
A corpus with 70 text documents
```

You can find more in the [tm package documentation](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tm/tm.pdf) under `tm_combine`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did not know about the updated tm manual. It was not in the previous tm manual (2010 or previous versions).

Answer (score 0):

I overcome this issue as well in the context of big data text mining sets. It was not possible to load the entire data set at once.

Here, another option for such big data sets is possible. The approach is to collect a vector of one document corpora inside a loop. After processing all documents like this, it is possible to convert this vector into one huge corpus e.g. to create a DTM on it.

```
# Vector to collect the corpora:
webCorpusCollection <- c()

# Loop over raw data:
for(i in ...) {

  try({      

    # Convert one document into a corpus:
    webDocument <- Corpus(VectorSource(iconv(webDocuments[i,1], "latin1", "UTF-8")))

    #
    # Do other things e.g. preprocessing...
    #

    # Store this document into the corpus vector:
    webCorpusCollection <- rbind(webCorpusCollection, webDocument)

  })
}

# Collecting done. Create one huge corpus:
webCorpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(unlist(webCorpusCollection[,"content"])))
```