# Use tm's Corpus function with big data in R

Tags: r, bigdata, text-mining, tm

I'm trying to do text mining on big data in R with `tm`.

I run into memory issues frequently (such as `can not allocation vector of size....` ) and use the established methods of troubleshooting those issues, such as

- using 64-bit R
- trying different OS's (Windows, Linux, Solaris, etc)
- setting `memory.limit()` to its maximum
- making sure that sufficient RAM and compute is available on the server (which there is)
- making liberal use of `gc()`
- profiling the code for bottlenecks
- breaking up big operations into multiple smaller operations

However, when trying to run `Corpus` on a vector of a million or so text fields, I encounter a slightly different memory error than usual and I'm not sure how to work-around the problem. The error is:

```
> ds <- Corpus(DataframeSource(dfs))
Error: memory exhausted (limit reached?)
```

Can (and should) I run `Corpus` incrementally on blocks of rows from that source dataframe then combine the results? Is there a more efficient way to run this?

The size of the data that will produce this error depends on the computer running it, but if you take the built-in `crude` dataset and replicate the documents until it's large enough, then you can replicate the error.

**UPDATE**

I've been experimenting with trying to combine smaller corpa, i.e.

```
test1 <- dfs[1:10000,]
test2 <- dfs[10001:20000,]

ds.1 <- Corpus(DataframeSource(test1))
ds.2 <- Corpus(DataframeSource(test2))
```

and while I haven't been successful, I did discover `tm_combine` which is [supposed to solve this exact problem](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tm/topics/tm_combine). The only catch is that for some reason, my 64-bit build of R 3.1.1 with the newest version of `tm` can't find the function `tm_combine`. Perhaps it was removed from the package for some reason? I'm investigating...

```
> require(tm)
> ds.12 <- tm_combine(ds.1,ds.2)
Error: could not find function "tm_combine"
```

Comment: Is all your code in a single function?  Or a script?

Comment: it's a script at the moment

Comment: I'm guessing that your code may be making too many copies...but I'll wait for the experts.

Comment: Fair enough. Right now it's just the source dataframe and the non-working `Corpus` command in the environment though.

Comment: can you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: @JamesTobin normally I would, but the size of data that causes this error depends entirely on the computer running it, so there's no one example that would reproduce the error for everyone else. It's just a dataframe with a little over 1 million rows of arbitrary text data. I've got 16 CPU cores and 40GB of RAM on this machine. But it's the same as if you use the built-in "crude" dataset and made it 50,000 times longer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if `tm_combine` became deprecated or why it's not found in the `tm` namespace, but I did find a solution through using `Corpus` on smaller chunks of the dataframe then combining them.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6616805/r-text-mining-package-allowing-to-incorporate-new-documents-into-an-existing-co/6617011#6617011) StackOverflow post had a simple way to do that without `tm_combine`:

```
test1 <- dfs[1:100000,]
test2 <- dfs[100001:200000,]

ds.1 <- Corpus(DataframeSource(test1))
ds.2 <- Corpus(DataframeSource(test2))

#ds.12 <- tm_combine(ds.1,ds.2) ##Error: could not find function "tm_combine"
ds.12 <- c(ds.1,ds.2)
```

which gives you:

> ds.12

```
<<VCorpus (documents: 200000, metadata (corpus/indexed): 0/0)>>
```

Sorry not to figure this out on my own before asking. I tried and failed with other ways of combining objects.